# Is there a way to read .csproj PropertyGroup variable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, environment-variables, dotnet-build

I'm looking to build selfcontained publishsingle file dotnet application. During dotnet publish, setting the environmentName variable from commandline. Is there a way to read this porpertyGroup variable in c#.

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --self-contained true  -p:EnvironmentName=Development -p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

Project.csproj

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'" >
  <EnvironmentName>Production</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>

<Choose>
  <When Condition=" '$(EnvironmentName)'=='Production' ">    
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Remove="**/Development/*.cs" />
      <Compile Remove="**/Staging/*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <When Condition=" '$(EnvironmentName)'=='Staging' ">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Remove="**/Production/*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    ...
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

C#

```
internal class Program
{
  private static async Task ConfigureBuilderAsync(IHostBuilder builder, string[] args)
  {
    await builder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(builder =>
    {
      ...
       
     // how to read csproj envName here in c#
      var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EnvironmentName");
      if (env == "Production")
      {
       _ = builder
        .SetBasePath(basedirectory!)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.production.json", false, false)
        .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
      }
      else
      {
        _ = builder
        .SetBasePath(basedirectory!)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.staging.json", true, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.development.json", true, true)
        .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    }
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The `IHostBuilder` is in the code of the program that is produced by building the .csproj? At the point where the program is being run, it has already been built and there is no property to read. If your program needs to know how it was built, you can as part of the build inject some code (such as an assembly attribute or a class) that the program can use.